# Python anaconda conda issue: updating anaconda package impossible because processes are running

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have an issue with updating anaconda's packages with conda. When I make a conda update --all, there is an issue which says to me:

```
Error: Unable to remove files for package: cryptography
Please close all processes running code from cryptography and try again.
```

However, none process are running, I have just the cmd window open.
Same story when I want update dateutile for instance.
It is like if conda uses some package and then I cannot update them?
Somebody knows a method to close or remove those packages in order to reinstall them?

For information:

```
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts>conda info -a
Current conda install:
platform : win-64
conda version : 3.11.0
conda-build version : 1.11.0
python version : 3.4.3.final.0
requests version : 2.6.2
root environment : C:\Anaconda3 (writable)
default environment : C:\Anaconda3
envs directories : C:\Anaconda3\envs
package cache : C:\Anaconda3\pkgs
channel URLs : https://conda.binstar.org/juanlu001/win-64/
https://conda.binstar.org/juanlu001/noarch/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
config file : C:\Users\maxime.condarc
is foreign system : False
```

Comment: If you run `conda --debug update --all` it should tell you which file is open that is preventing the update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This situation will be improved in the next version of conda, but for now, you can use `conda install -f cryptography` to force conda to update cryptography.

Comment: Tried that, did not work for me unfortunately (Win8.1)

Comment: Hmm. What happened exactly?

Comment: Returned the same error as if you would run `conda install` without `-f` parameter: `Error: Unable to remove files for package: cryptography`. I thought this is to be expected since there is a system lock on one of the files in `cryptography` package.

Comment: Sounds like you have a file or terminal open pointing into the package somewhere.

Comment: Worked for me for pip.  I had to install a package with pip as no conda version and then needed this to update to ipython 3.2.0

Comment: `pip install cryptography` should work too. Once you are able to run `conda update conda` successfully this error should go away.

Answer (score 2):

The reason conda fails to update this packages is because when you call `conda install` or `conda update` in the **default environment** it connects to internet to get latest versions.
And to do this conda uses `cryptography` library from the **default environment** and therefore it locks this file:

```
<Anaconda_folder_path>/Lib/site-packages/cryptography-0.8.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_f3e4673fx399b1113.pyd
```

So to overcome this particular problem you could install the latest `cryptography` package in offline mode thus avoiding conda locking that file.

If you have tried and failed to update the package - it has already been downloaded and its path should be: `<Anaconda_folder_path>/pkgs/cryptography-0.8.2-py27_0.tar.bz2` (If not you might need to manually download it).

Copy this file to any other location and then isntall the package in offline mode:

```
conda install <path_to_new_location>cryptography-0.8.2-py27_0.tar.bz2
```

This has fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Ok, I see. It is a bit odd to me because the interest of update --all is to not make all the updates manually.
Your technique works well and indeed, all packages were already downloaded in the pkgs folder that you mentioned.
Thanks a lot for your answer. I cannot tag your answer as a good one because I don't have enough points but It helps me alot.

Comment: Glad  it helped. However: `Basic use of the site, including asking questions, answering, and suggesting edits, does not require any reputation at all`. Perhaps [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) can help to figure out how to handle answers...